# Python: check for existence of a non-directory file at a given path

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I have a directory with a lot of files (~1.4M) from a data-dump and I want to sort them into subdirectories to create batches of smaller size.
Due to the large number of files in the directory I want to batchify, I want to avoid having to `os.listdir(...)` everything in the directory and then test all of the results if they are a directory or not.

My idea until now is to use `os.walk(...)` to check this.

Is there a more pythonic/efficient way to achieve what I want?

Comment: [`glob.iglob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.iglob)? `os.walk` will also descent into subdirectories, while `glob.(i)glob` will not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to `os.listdir()`, you can use `os.scandir()` on Python 3.5+.  This returns an iterator of `DirEntry` objects and does not recurse into sub-directories as is the case with `os.walk`.

Here's an example from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.scandir):

```
for entry in os.scandir(path):
   if not entry.name.startswith('.') and entry.is_file():
       print(entry.name)
```